# PDFX: Unicode in title

Tags: pdfx

I try to get an PDF/A document and followed different samples. When using `pdfx` to my understanding I cannot use any longer `\hyperref` package. Therefore I have problems to set the encoding. I have the following MWE

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{a-3b}{pdfx}
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfa, pdfencoding=auto}{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{filecontents} %if filecontents should overwrite old files
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.xmpdata}
    \Title{My Title möglich ÖÜß } % <--------------------- not encoded
    \Author{John Doe}
    \Source{my test} %<-------- not used
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfx}
% \usepackage{hyperref} % comment out if using the 'pdfx' package

\hypersetup{%
    anchorcolor        = black,
    unicode            = true,
}%

% ---------- packages to be loaded after hyperref ----------%

\usepackage{bookmark} % does not work with pdfx package in lualatex?

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Second}
\section{New section}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Newer section}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

According to the documentation 2.4 all UTF-8 chars are allowed. [image]

So my major problem is how to set the encoding properly?

Comment: is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: This works for me, and I have TeXlive 2017...

Comment: Your document was saved as UTF-8 (good), but is being read as ISO 8859-1 aka Latin 1 (bad). At least one part of your toolchain seems not to be fully Unicode-aware.

Comment: Maybe it's just your viewer? Your document compiles just fine for me (LuaLaTeX).

Comment: If I set the same Text with `hyperref` I face the same Problem untlil I set  `pdfencoding=auto`. So I have no clue why this approach has a different result. I'm working on a Linux and the system is more or less up2date. I think the packages are from March20 but I have serious problems to check in detail.

Comment: @Ingmar: Just a thought: might it be that the `filecontents` writes the wrong encoding under Linux?